# Extension of a field monomorphism to an automorphism .

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $E$ be the splitting field of a polynomial $f$ over $k.$ Let $k \subset K \subset E,$ then show that any $k-$monomorphism $\phi$ from $K \to E$ can be extended to a $k-$ automorphism from $E \to E.$

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$ Let $[E : k]=n$ and let $B =\{\beta_i \}_{i=1}^n$ is a basis of $E$ over $k.$

Then, wlg, let $\{\beta_i \}_{i=1}^m$ be a basis of $K$ over $k.$ Then, $\beta_1=\{\phi (\beta_i) \}_{i=1}^m$ is a basis of some sub field of $E.$

Now, I am thinking we have to extend
the basis $\beta_1$ of $K$ to that we obtain a basis of $E.$ is $k.$

A small hint is warmly appreciated .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Hint/advice: I don't think you'll need the bases. Use the fact that $E=k(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_d)$, where the $\alpha_i$ are roots of $f$. It may help to start by assuming $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: Yes, but how shall I proceed after that?